# How to find the C satisfied $\left| y\left( t\right) \right| < Ct$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$a\left( t\right)$ is a continuity function on $R^{+}$ (x>0), $y\left( t\right)$ is a function
satisfied the equation $y''+a\left( t\right)y=0$, if $\int _{0}^{+\infty }t|a\left( t\right)|dt < \infty$，prove there exist a C>0 (C is a constant)，such that if $t\in R^{+}
$ and t is large enough, $|y\left( t\right)|\leq Ct$.

I don't know where to start ,how to use the differential equation

Comment: Write $y$ as an integral of $y'$. Then integrate by parts to create $y''$ there. Then use the equation.

Comment: @PavelM.Thanks, I will try it later.

Comment: See this link. I think it inspires us for the question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation